# Monogame: error MSB3073: The command "dotnet tool restore" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, game-development, monogame, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to use Monogame on Visual Studio 2022, and when I try to build an empty project, I receive a partial restore error. No solutions presented on Google so far have solved the issue.

```
    Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\johnk\AppData\Local\Temp\denfz23c.23a\restore.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package dotnet-mgcb-editor-windows with version (= 3.8.1.263)
1>C:\Users\johnk\AppData\Local\Temp\denfz23c.23a\restore.csproj : error NU1102: - Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 3.8.1.1-develop ]
1>C:\Users\johnk\AppData\Local\Temp\denfz23c.23a\restore.csproj : error NU1102: - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
1>
1>Package "dotnet-mgcb-editor-windows" failed to restore, due to Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageException: The tool package could not be restored.
1>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ProjectRestorer.Restore(FilePath project, PackageLocation packageLocation, String verbosity)
1>   at Microsoft.DotNet.ToolPackage.ToolPackageInstaller.InstallPackageToExternalManagedLocation(PackageLocation packageLocation, PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, String targetFramework, String verbosity)
1>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Restore.ToolRestoreCommand.InstallPackages(ToolManifestPackage package, Nullable`1 configFile)
1>
1>Tool 'dotnet-mgcb' (version '3.8.1.263') was restored. Available commands: mgcb
1>Tool 'dotnet-mgcb-editor' (version '3.8.1.263') was restored. Available commands: mgcb-editor
1>
1>Restore partially failed.
1>Tool 'dotnet-mgcb-editor-linux' (version '3.8.1.263') was restored. Available commands: mgcb-editor-linux
1>Tool 'dotnet-mgcb-editor-mac' (version '3.8.1.263') was restored. Available commands: mgcb-editor-mac
1>C:\Users\johnk\.nuget\packages\monogame.content.builder.task\3.8.1.263\build\MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task.targets(139,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet tool restore" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "Project1.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: [Last updated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-mgcb-editor/#versions-body-tab) 3 hours ago, 0 downloads.  Looks like they'll have to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem because `.config/dotnet-tools.json` was marked by Windows as unsafe.

Solution: go to the properties of this file and check "Unblock". Then everything worked as expected.

Another solution I found is unblocking the zip file where all files were stored in before extracting the zip file.

[Properties dialog with Unblock checkbox at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihSgG.png)

Comment: This was an odd one but it helped me. Thank you!

Comment: This totally solved my issue. +1
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using vscode to build the project and was able to solve the issue by editing the file .config/dotnet-tools.json with the most recent version of the dotnet-mgcb-editor-windows package 3.8.1.303

My file:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-mgcb": {
      "version": "3.8.1.303",
      "commands": [
        "mgcb"
      ]
    },
    "dotnet-mgcb-editor": {
      "version": "3.8.1.303",
      "commands": [
        "mgcb-editor"
      ]
    },
    "dotnet-mgcb-editor-linux": {
      "version": "3.8.1.303",
      "commands": [
        "mgcb-editor-linux"
      ]
    },
    "dotnet-mgcb-editor-windows": {
      "version": "3.8.1.303",
      "commands": [
        "mgcb-editor-windows"
      ]
    },
    "dotnet-mgcb-editor-mac": {
      "version": "3.8.1.303",
      "commands": [
        "mgcb-editor-mac"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer. I installed the Monogame Project extensions, created a couple projects and ran into this error.  The error disappeared and I can compile debug Monogame Projects.